# Select all the rows with same id and same value in another column without using having clause

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have cosmos DB with a container having multiple documents. I want to get all the ids with the same value of a property. Since it's Cosmos I cannot use the having clause.

eg: If there is a container with the schema,

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "source": "online",
 "type": "login"
},
{
 "id": 1,
 "source": "online",
 "type": "login"
},
{
 "id": 2,
 "source": "online",
 "type": "login"
},
{
 "id": 2,
 "source": "In store",
 "type": "login"
}
```

I want all the ids where the source value is all same and "online". So in the above example, it should return "id" as 1 only.

Comment: Please edit to show your expected output. Also, please show your query attempt and the issue(s) you're running into.

Answer (score 0):

This request selects all IDs that did not have other source types at all, only those online

```
 select distinct(id), source
    from(
    select id, source
    from your_table as t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id
                                   FROM your_table 
                                   WHERE source != 'online'
                                   AND   your_table.id = t.id))x
```

-- If need at the end use this  `WHERE x.id IS NOT NULL`

---

Result :

```
| id   | source 
|:---- |:------:
| 1    | online
```

Comment: May be I didn't explain it well because what I want is only the ids where all the source are "online" only. So it should only return id = 1 in above e.g. as it is the only id with all the source as "online"

Comment: @Amit Oh so if ID have `online` and `In store` you no need this ID, yes ?

Comment: @Amit Check now